# Helm Occur - jump to next (or previous) occurence

Tags: helm, search, occur, emacs25

my **emacs settings**

```
➜  settings git:(develop) ag 'occur'                    
helm-settings.el
38:(global-set-key (kbd "C-s")  'helm-occur)
```

[image]

How to jump between different search results while you're in edit screen (i.e. not to invoke the helm-occur screen each time). Before the helm-occur mapping - it was simply a continuation of **C-s** clicks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`M-x next-error` (typically bound to `` C-x ` ``) will jump to matches in the occur buffer.

Comment: There is another default binding for `next-error`, namely `M-g M-n`, which I prefer because it has a companion binding for `previous-error`, `M-g M-p`.

Comment: I have rebound M-<up> and M-<down> to next-error and previous error, FWIW.

Comment: Those are nice bindings, @Realraptoy! It seems that of the major modes I tend to use, only Org Mode has a binding defined for those keys, but in Org Mode I don't need `next-error` and `previous-errror`.